# append text to lines

Tags: python

I am having a text file like below. I am trying to move all the text on to a new line.

Help me the possible ways in regex.

Please help to get the output.

Input:

```
Tel : 03-33416909 Fax : 03-33412909
GST No: 1234567890

 

CELCOM (M) COMMUNICATION BHD                                                       PURCHASE ORDER
33-37 MENARA CELCOM                                                                        Please quote this number on all correspondence
7 JALAN 89

KAW PERUSAHAAN                                                                          no. PO-00027

54098 SJ

Attn = MS SIM                                                                               DATE —_: 07/06/2015

TEL:  03-56801313                                                                     TERMS . 45 Days
```

Expected output:

```
Tel : 03-33416909 Fax : 03-33412909
GST No: 1234567890

 

CELCOM (M) COMMUNICATION BHD                                                       
33-37 MENARA CELCOM                                                                      
7 JALAN 89

KAW PERUSAHAAN                                                                          

54098 SJ

Attn = MS SIM                                                                               

TEL:  03-56801313                                                                     

###  -- note the right side lines from here

PURCHASE ORDER
Please quote this number on all correspondence

no. PO-00027

DATE —_: 07/06/2015

TERMS . 45 Days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the lines with a regex on 5 or more spaces, store the left and right parts separately, and join them at the end:

```
data = """Tel : 03-33416909 Fax : 03-33412909
GST No: 1234567890

 

CELCOM (M) COMMUNICATION BHD                       PURCHASE ORDER
33-37 MENARA CELCOM                               Please quote this number on all correspondence
7 JALAN 89

KAW PERUSAHAAN                                                                          no. PO-00027

54098 SJ

Attn = MS SIM                                      DATE —_: 07/06/2015

TEL:  03-56801313                                 TERMS . 45 Days"""

import re
from itertools import chain

def join_blocks(data):
    left = []
    right = []
    
    for line in data.splitlines():
        parts = re.split(r' {5,}', line)
        left.append(parts[0])
        if len(parts) > 1:
            right.append(parts[1])
        else:
            right.append('')
    return '\n'.join(chain(left, right))

print(join_blocks(data))
```

Output:

```
Tel : 03-33416909 Fax : 03-33412909
GST No: 1234567890

 

CELCOM (M) COMMUNICATION BHD
33-37 MENARA CELCOM
7 JALAN 89

KAW PERUSAHAAN

54098 SJ

Attn = MS SIM

TEL:  03-56801313





PURCHASE ORDER
Please quote this number on all correspondence


no. PO-00027



DATE —_: 07/06/2015

TERMS . 45 Days
Entrée [ ]:
￼
​
```

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is your string, you can use `re.split` (regex split) with more than 8 spaces (as of a tab) and join them with newlines:

```
import re
print("\n".join(re.split('\s{8,}',s,flags=re.MULTILINE)))
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output at all. The OP wants to append the whole block on the right after the whole left block.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line, save the right part in a buffer and write the left part immediately. Then, just write the buffer to the file:

```py
import re

spaces = 8
buffer = []

with open("input.txt") as f_in, open("output.txt", 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        parts = re.split(rf"\s{{{spaces},}}", line.strip())
        f_out.write(parts[0]+'\n')
        buffer.extend(parts[1:])

    f_out.write("\n Right part of lines\n")

    f_out.writelines('\n'.join(buffer))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

first_col, second_col = [], []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        rows = re.split('\s{8,}', line.strip())
        first_col.append(rows[0])
        if len(rows) > 1:
            second_col.append(rows[1])
        elif second_col:
            second_col.append('')

print(*first_col, '\n###  -- note the right side lines from here\n', *second_col, sep='\n')
```